# Inserting large JSON strings into DynamoDB for querying

Tags: php, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using the AWS PHP SDK. I have millions of records in my RDS that contain large JSON files. I'd like to send all of these into DynamoDB for easier querying and logging instead of bombarding my RDS DBs.

Unfortunately I get this error anytime that I try to add a new record (putItem). Can you help?

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Aws\DynamoDb\Exception\DynamoDbException: AWS Error Code: SerializationException, Status Code: 400, AWS Request ID: IBB453LGDITFME8Q1G87AP9RCJVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG, AWS Error Type: client, AWS Error Message: Start of list found where not expected, User-Agent: aws-sdk-php2/2.7.7 Guzzle/3.9.2 curl/7.28.1 PHP/5.5.10
  thrown in <b>/Users/alex/Development/AWS/PHP SDK/Aws/Common/Exception/NamespaceExceptionFactory.php</b> on line <b>91</b><br />
```

Here is my PHP code: https://gist.github.com/nyalex/9004acbc4b2cabd5333b

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I wasn't using the proper array format for the putItem() input. Here is what worked for me:

```
// Convert JSON for AWS
$m = new Marshaler();

// Send to DynamoDB
$result = $client->putItem(array(
    'TableName' => 'test',
    'Item' => $m->marshalItem(
        array(
            'client_id'      => 100,
            'order_id'      => '200',
            'time'    => time(),
            'order' => $order_json
        )
    ),
    'ReturnConsumedCapacity' => 'TOTAL'
));
```